PHPStan not recognizing type specification for generic type
PHPStan is not recognizing my type specification in my docblock preceeding a method.
Here's the code:
/**
* Process (resize and save) all versions of an uploaded file
*
* @param UploadedFileInterface   $file   The uploaded file.
* @param-out TypedArray<int, VersionData> $versionsData
*                                        A reference to a typed array of VersionData objects
*                                        Paths are relative to the base photo path.
* @param-out string              $error  An error message if one was encountered.
*
* @return bool
*/
public function processAllVersions(UploadedFileInterface $file, TypedArray &$versionsData, string &$error): bool

I'm getting an error on the public... line that "Method Api\Helpers\Image\Processor::processAllVersions() has parameter $versionsData with generic class Api\Helpers\TypedArray but does not specify its types: TKey, TValue"
TypedArray is defined & commented like:
/**
 * Implements, as much as possible, a typed array.
 *
 * @template TKey
 * @template TValue
 * @implements ArrayAccess<TKey, TValue>
 * @implements Iterator<TKey, TValue>

 */
class TypedArray implements ArrayAccess, Countable, Iterator, JsonSerializable

I've used it elsewhere in my project, defining the key and value just fine.
I think I'm very much defining the type (int, VersionData - VersionData is a class in the same namespace).  If I change the value type to "string", I get downstream errors - so obviously at least part of PHPStan is reading that declaration.
What am I missing?
